# Trying to get my banner image to span the width of the page

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I'm creating a blog and I'm trying to get an image just below the nav bar. I've got four images that slides using css and js. However no matter how I try I can't get the images to span the width of the page. I've tried 100% width, vw, etc. Nothing is working how I want it to. Here is the html and css (bear in mind I've been playing with the css alot)

```
 #stage {
margin: 1em auto;
width: 100%;
height: 292px;
margin-bottom: 40px;
}

#stage a {
    position: absolute;
  }
  #stage a img {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background: #fff;
  }

  #stage a:nth-of-type(1) {
    animation-name: fader;
    animation-delay: 4s;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    z-index: 20;
  }
  #stage a:nth-of-type(2) {
    z-index: 10;
  }
  #stage a:nth-of-type(n+3) {
    display: none;
  }

  @keyframes fader {
    from { opacity: 1.0; }
    to   { opacity: 0.0; }
  }
```

and here is the html

```
<div id="stage">
<a><%= image_tag "2.jpeg" %></a>
<a><%= image_tag "1.jpeg" %></a>
<a><%= image_tag "3.png" %></a>
<a><%= image_tag "4.jpeg" %></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Set the image as a background to a div, then use `background-size: cover` to stretch it to the width of the div. You can also use `background-position: center` to center it.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps. I've documented the changes in the CSS code. Be aware though that depending on the actual image, it could be blown out of proportions.

```css
#stage {
  margin: 1em auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 292px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

#stage a {
  position: absolute;
  width: inherit; /* Added */
  height: inherit; /* Added */
}

#stage a img {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #fff;
  width: inherit; /* Added */
  height: inherit; /* Added */
}

#stage a:nth-of-type(1) {
  animation-name: fader;
  animation-delay: 4s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  z-index: 20;
}

#stage a:nth-of-type(2) {
  z-index: 10;
}

#stage a:nth-of-type(n+3) {
  display: none;
}

@keyframes fader {
  from {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="stage">
  <a>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100/000000">
  </a>
  <a>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100/ff0000">
  </a>
  <a>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100/00ff00">
  </a>
  <a>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100/0000ff">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to answer. Maybe the size of the images is the problem. What size would you recommend using (I know one of them is over 7mb) and also after the first image slides the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th just slightly to the right. Do you know why that is?

Comment: Never mind. I got that last part sorted. Thank you so much!